# Can't access getters in the store for Vue when in a template because it "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm new to vue and vuex and I'm also using Nuxt. I want to use a function in my template that searches for some data that I fetched from an API (in vuex). I can't figute out why I always get

```
state.allHandhelds.values.findIndex is not a function
```

My template is like this:

```
<div>{{ handheldID("Form Factor") }}</div>
```

And in my computed I call the function like this:

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["allHandhelds"]),
    handheldID(merkmal) {
      return this.$store.getters.indexFinder(merkmal);
    },
  },
```

In vuex I have it defined as a getter:

```
export const getters = {
   indexFinder(state, merkmal) {
    return state.allHandhelds.values.findIndex(
      (el) => el === merkmal
    ); /* Index des Merkmals finden */
  },
};
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

You've to use the method access style like :

```js
export const getters = {

 indexFinder: (state) => (merkmal) => {
      return state.allHandhelds.values.findIndex(
         (el) => el === merkmal
    ); 
  }
};
```

or with syntax :

```js
export const getters = {
   indexFinder(state) {
    return (merkmal)=> {
       return state.allHandhelds.values.findIndex(
      (el) => el === merkmal
    ); /* Index des Merkmals finden */
   }  
},
};
```

Comment: That didn't work. I unfortunately still get the "state.allHandhelds.values.findIndex is not a function" error

Comment: please share how do you define the state

Comment: There is a problem with thje data loading. If  i just return "return state.allHandhelds.values" from the getter it works and if I then afterwards attach the .findIndex it also works but as soon as I reload the page it breaks again.

Is it because I have a fetch in my store too, that gets the data?

`export const actions = {
  fetchAllHandhelds(context) {
    return fetch(URLisHERE)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        context.commit("setHandhelds", data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  },
};
`

Comment: And I define the state like this:

`export const state = () => ({
  allHandhelds: [],
});`

Comment: according to the state you should do  `state.allHandhelds.findIndex(`